# Mute python fpdf.multi_cell in console

Tags: python, pyfpdf

There's code part like:

```
for j, row in enumerate(data):
    for datum in row:
        line_height = lh_list[j]  # choose right height for current row
        if datum is row[0]:
            pdf.set_font("Times", 'B', size=8)
            pdf.multi_cell(col_width_name, line_height, datum, border=1, align='L', ln=3,
                           max_line_height=pdf.font_size, fill=True)
        else:
            pdf.set_font("Times", size=8)
            pdf.multi_cell(col_width_value, line_height, datum, border=1, align='C', ln=3,
                           max_line_height=pdf.font_size)
    pdf.ln(line_height)
```

it works fine, but because of multi_cell() method there are prints in console. If there's a possibility to mute/turn off that printing?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding this code:

```
@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
```